# Can a contract deployed on goerli or sepolia accept Matic?

Tags: blockchain, polygon

I'm building a contract, in which you can pay with a variety of tokens. I have added ETH and WETH and I wanted to ask if a contract that is going to be deployed on goerli or sepolia can accept MATIC tokens.

consequently, can it accept bitcoin (I highly doubt this), BNB or any other coin / token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,

Matic or Bitcoin or BNB tokens, they are the native currencies of their respective chains. They can't be used an smart contract. This is the reason we have a concept of  Wrapped Bitcoin , Wrapped Ether what you called Weth. This Wrapped token simply serves as an alias for the original token in a different chain.

I am not experienced with Bridges Yet so can't tell you about them. BUt you can check them out, Bridges may solve this problem, and if you learn anything helpful with bridges then consider sharing it here.